# sql select statement within if condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I want to create a statement like the following:

```
if (select statement1 returns rows){
   select statement2
}
else {
  select statement3
}
```

This `if` statement is part of a bigger query

```
   select from products where p.id in (
        if (select statement1 returns rows){
           select statement2
       }
       else {
        select statement3
      }
```

Is this possible in SQL Server, or is my thinking incorrect?

Comment: I presume you are wanting to run this against a database using C#?

Comment: What is the context of this select statement? Are you testing for an optional parameter in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `EXISTS` and `CASE..END`:

```
select *
from products
where p.id in (
  case when (exists ( <statement1> ))
    then ( <statement2> )
    else ( <statement3> )
  end
)
```

Where `<statement1>` might be: `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Id = 123`

`<statement2>` might be: `SELECT MIN(field) FROM someTable`

`<statement3>` might be: `SELECT 0 as DefaultValue`

If you can show some examples of what you want those actual statements to be I can provide a more concrete answer.

Comment: thanks! thats all i needed to get started. the inner queries were confusing in my case but i figured them out.

Answer (score 1):

Actually SQL is more rigid, due to performance considerations. Your query will look more like this:

```
select *
from products
where  1 = case when (exists ( <statement1> ))
              then case when p.id in ( <statement2> ) then 1 else 0 end
              else case when p.id in ( <statement3> ) then 1 else 0 end
           end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are checking for the same `id` existance, I think you could do a `UNION` here.

```
select *
from products 
where p.id in  (select id from table1
                union 
                select id from table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a UNION between your two conditions to help avoid performance problems...and may be easier to read as well.

```
    SELECT FROM products p
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT STATEMENT1)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT STATEMENT2 s2 WHERE s2.p_id = p.id)
    UNION
    SELECT FROM products p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT STATEMENT1)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT STATEMENT3 s3 WHERE s3.p_id = p.id)
```

Depending on the nature of the statements, you might be able to leave off the Not Exists in the second select.